# Problem completing Async Promise in Javascript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

[image]

My research suggests that creating an async class method is possible but I've found myself going in loops trying to get the values from a promise in my camera config class for a three.js project. So far the geometry is all located on the server and is sent to the browser on a different API without issue. I also need to send some site parameters from the server for the camera animation to work correctly and that is where I'm having a problem.

On the client's browser I set up the camera config class which is then used by multiple functions to center and move the camera in relation to the overall geometry. I thought it would be helpful to reuse the `offset2middle` value since it's already precalculated on the node server. However, I can't seem to find a convenient way to get the values directly into `this.cameracenter`. I need the values directly because I plan to do further manipulation of the values in the various camera animation functions to make sure the motion looks polished.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how this can be accomplished?

```
//All in the render.js file for the client
async function get_field_parameters() {
    // gets field parameters from server using standard node js api
    const response = await fetch(`/get-field-parameters/`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

// Camera Config Class
class SCREEN_DATA {
    constructor(window) {
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.aspect = this.width / this.height;
        this.fov = 80;
        this.camerafocus = this.find_center();
    }
    //Method
    async find_center() {
        let p = await get_field_parameters();
        return p.offset2middle;
    }
}
camera_config = new SCREEN_DATA(window); // screen Configuration

// Example of how I'd like to use the values
function main_camera(config) {
    console.log(config.camerafocus); // return [[PromiseResult]]: Object x: 50 y: 0 z: 50
    // Animated Camera
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(config.fov, config.aspect, 1, 400);
    camera.position.set(200, 100, 100); // start
    camera.lookAt(50, 0, 50); // Want to use camera focus values here
    return camera;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the results of `find_center`?  Where are you trying to do that, I don't see it used...

Comment: You can't turn async code into sync code. If a method is labeled with `async` it always returns a promise. So the extra `await`s here just add wrappers, it's not like they unpack the promise and convert it into sync code. Wherever you need to use the value, you have to `await`, `then` or provide a callback. A lot of this can be avoided with proper design, but there's not enough context to really offer a better design for this use case. What I can suggest is that if the class depends on fetched values in the constructor, fetch the values and `.then` build the class when the fetch resolves.

Comment: Where are you calling `find_center`? And where `main_camera`?